# Drupal 8 updating/synchronize database from dev to production

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-8

maybe you guys have some nice ideas, how to update d8 database, from dev version to production. Im learning d8 now and im wonder what if i run d8 site, with a lot of content, and still working on it on my local env. I can always synchronize database, to use real content on my local env but its wrong... i cant do it if users still modify content on production site.
Only few ideas now:

- create modules with exported new fields etc. to import on production site, but there is also a lot of configuration, other tables
- manually export parts of database. A lot of work!
- I can work on production site, making backups etc. dont like it, dont wont it, no way ;)

Do you have better ideas to synchronize two D8 apps?

Comment: Its called Backup and Restore. You backup the LIVE site _Dont you?_ So just restore that database to your dev machine

Comment: what if i need to work 8 hours on new feature, and content on production site change 1-5 times in one hour? i cant block production site for users that long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 8 most if not all of the configuration can be exported into the sync directory. Something like sites/default/files/config_HASH/_sync/ depending on your installation. However, you can [change that to another directory](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/changing-the-storage-location-of-the-sync-directory). You can include this directory inside your git repo and have a good workflow of working locally, pushing to staging, and the production. I would highly recommend you read these post about Drupal's configuration:

- https://chromatichq.com/blog/drupal-8-configuration-management-solving-configuration-conundrum
- https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/config/

I would also recommend you use [Drush](http://www.drush.org/en/master/) and [Drupal Console](https://drupalconsole.com/), it will make your life easier. Here's an example of my current workflow with these tools:

1. With Drupal Console I generate a module: `drupal generate:module`
2. Generate a controller: `drupal generate:controller`
3. Create Config Form: `drupal generate:form:config`
4. Enable the module: 'drush en name_of_module`
5. Export Configuration: `drupal config:export`
6. Commit and push my changes.
7. Import the configuration: `drush cim -y`

I would avoid exporting and importing databases as a workflow, it can get very tedious. However, you can use Drush to easily create SQL files and importing them.

Answer (score 0):

Now i see there is: Configuration export/import option integrated with Drupal 8:

> /admin/config/development/configuration

I will test it, read about it. For now i see that is perfect module! Exports all fields, configuration options and i can even choose what import/export.
More informations available here:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/managing-your-sites-configuration